# Seaborn grouped Bar plot

Tags: seaborn, data-visualization, bar-chart

I am trying to create visualizations for recent commonwealth medal tally dataset.
I would like to create a grouped bar chart of top ten countries by total number of medals won.
Y axis  =  total
x axis  =  Country name
How can I divide totals into three bars consisting of no of  :
**gold**, **Silver**,**Bronze** medals won by each country?

I created one using excel, but don't know how to do it using seaborn

P.S. I have already tried using a list of columns for hue.

```
df_10  =  df.head(10)
sns.barplot(data  = df_10, x  = 'team' , y = 'total' , hue = df_10[["gold" , 
"silver","bronze"]].apply(tuple , axis = 1) )
```

Here is the chart that I created using excel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws8Hc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the graph, you will need to change the dataframe to the format that will allow for easy plotting. One of the ways to do this is using `dataframe.melt()`. The method used by you may not work... Once the data is in a format that seaborn understands easily, plotting will become simple. As you have not provided the format for `df_10`, I have assumed the data to have 4 columns - Country, Gold, Silver and Bronze. Below is the code...

```
## Use melt using Country as ID and G, S, B as the rows for values
df_10 = pd.melt(df_10, id_vars=['Country'], value_vars=['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze'])
df_10.rename(columns={'value':'Count', 'variable':'Medals'}, inplace=True) ##Rename so the plot has informative texts
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7))  ## Set figure size
ax=sns.barplot(data=df_10, x='Country', y='Count', hue='Medals') ## Plot the graph
```

[image]